# How to bind validators to TextFields in vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to bind a custom validator to a `TextField` `BeanFieldGroup` in vaadin.

Although my validator only returns `true`, the validation fails each time. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class Order {
    private BigDecimal price;
}

class MyView {


public void init() {
    TextField priceField = new TextField("Enter Price");
    BeanFieldGroup<Order> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<Order>(Order.class);
    binder.bind(priceField, "price");

    priceField.addValidator(new AbstractValidator<String>("Price invalid") {
            @Override
            protected boolean isValidValue(String value) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<String> getType() {
                return String.class;
            }
    });

    Button saveButton = new SaveButton("Save", new ClickListener() {
        try {
            editor.commit();
        } catch (CommitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showValidationErrors(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Result: whenever I commit the binder, I'm getting the error `com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup$CommitException: Commit failed` `Price invalid`.

So, although I always return true by the validator, it's not working. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question: the validator has to be of the same type of the binding property. Changing to `AbstractValidator<BigDecimal>` solves the error.

Comment: Hi, i'm new to Vaadin framework. I"m trying to do validate the text field. When i submit for the first time, then the validation went successful. But if post next immediately with the same value, at receiving end i'm loosing value. Is this due to validation what we have done?